# Plotting selected explanatory variables in multiple linear regression with interaction terms

Tags: data-visualization, multiple-regression

I have a question about plotting multiple linear regression results.
I would like two graphs, one that shows the estimated relationship between d15N and avomc, and another that shows the relationship between d15N and N.

My questions are:
What are the equations giving the fitted values for these two relationships?
Does it make sense to plot such a thing?

```
Call:
lm(formula = d15N ~ avomc + N + fPlant + fGrazing + fblock + 
fPlant:fGrazing, data = D_data)

Residuals:
 Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.50874 -0.47156  0.02093  0.56252  2.04284 

Coefficients:
                           Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                   -0.428674   0.848159  -0.505 0.614178    
avomc                        -17.400385   6.620888  -2.628 0.009689 ** 
N                              0.541445   0.192159   2.818 0.005645 ** 
fPlantPcrantzii               -1.260810   0.293716  -4.293 3.56e-05 ***
fPlantSvirgaurea              -2.170915   0.277706  -7.817 2.15e-12 ***
fGrazingout                   -0.002856   0.263470  -0.011 0.991368    
fblock2                        1.203011   0.313434   3.838 0.000198 ***
fblock3                        1.053795   0.319100   3.302 0.001258 ** 
fblock4                       -0.153207   0.294686  -0.520 0.604076    
fblock5                        0.379873   0.292868   1.297 0.197051    
fblock6                       -1.015164   0.292780  -3.467 0.000727 ***
fPlantPcrantzii:fGrazingout   -0.875229   0.398690  -2.195 0.030037 *  
fPlantSvirgaurea:fGrazingout  -0.040601   0.361892  -0.112 0.910857
```

Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: I am confused by your question because there don't seem to be any interactions that include your two covariates of interest.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "the dependency of"?

If you save your model (as, say `mod1`) and then use `plot(mod1)` you will get several useful plots. Is one of those what you want?

Another thing you can do is to plot the relationship between d15N and avomc at certain levels of the other variables (e.g. medians for continuous variables; most frequent level for categorical ones; or possibly multiple levels of each variable).

Comment: If I am remebering right with plot() I will get the diagnostic plot of my model. What I would like to do instead is to show graphycally, in a nice way, the relationship between dN15 and N and d15n and avomc, and if possible I would like to avoid to make separate graph for each level of the other categorical variable. Does it make any sense?

Comment: If you pick only one level of each categorical variable, you won't see the interactions.